# Swift Generics: Cannot convert class and subtype existential value to expected argument type

Tags: swift, generics

Given

```
typealias CP = C & P
protocol P {}
class C {}
class D: C, P {}
```

and

```
func f<T: C>(ofType: T.Type) {}
```

and given `CP` is compatible with `C` as expected:

```
let cp: CP = D()
let c: C = cp
```

why is does the following error?

```
f(ofType: CP.self)
```

> error: cannot convert value of type 'CP.Protocol' (aka '(C & P).Protocol') to expected argument type 'C.Type'

---

The ability to declare existentials of classes and protocols was added to Swift in version 4, see [SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another instance of "protocols do not conform to themselves." While `CP` describes a type that is promised to be both a subclass of `C` and an implementor of `P`, it is not *itself* either of those things.

Consider the case where `C` has a required init, and `f()` calls it:

```
class C {
    required init() {}
}


func f<T: C>(ofType: T.Type) {
    T()
}

f(ofType: CP.self)
```

This is the equivalent of calling `CP()` directly. But what `init` should be called in that case? `CP` is a requirement that the type be *some* subclass of `C`, but which one? It can't even be `C`, because `C` doesn't conform to `P`. So what should Swift construct?